# Is there a word for a character being a number, letter, or underscore?

Tags: single-word-requests

**Edit: Close this question as it doesn’t relate to English.**

I know the term "alphanumeric" means a character is a letter or number, but is there a term that includes underscores? So `_`, `A`, and `9` would all fit this definition.

The exact characters that fit this definition are as follows: `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (and no non-English letters like `â`, `é`, `ł`, or anything else that isn’t in the normal English alphabet)

The following characters do **not** fit this definition: `&`, `/`, `~`, `â`, `+`.

The following characters **do** fit this definition: `A`, `b`, `4`, `_`, `9`, `z`

Example context (missing term is *x*):

- "_ah7" contains all *x* characters.
- "hg8&" contains non-*x* characters.

I've tried searching this up, but all the results are irrelevant garbage.

Quick thing to add: Yes, it is reasonable that a term like this exists because almost every single programming language that is based on English allows identifiers to be alphanumeric characters or underscores where the first character is not a number. This is consistent among thousands who know different languages- the better question would be why isn't it a term already (if it isn't)?

Comment: You want to invent a category, but with an established name, for alphanumeric characters plus underscore but not ampersand?

Comment: @YosefBaskin no I am looking for a word that describe a characters that is either alphanumeric or an underscore. An ampersand does *not* fit this definition, but not alone, but with many others such as `$`, `!`, `*`, and so on

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's unrealistic. What about 'a term for all letters, all numerals, and the backslash'? Or 'all letters, odd numbers, the pilcrow and the cedilla'?

Comment: @Penguin Could you give the sentence and context in which you want to use this adjective? My thought is that you state that "A-Z (upper- and lowercase), 0 - 9 and _ are valid characters" and use "valid characters" thereafter.

Comment: @Greybeard the adjective usage can be found labeled in the question as “Example context (missing term is *x*)” there are 2 sentence examples right there

Comment: This is not a question about the English language, but rather about computer jargon.  You probably should be asking it on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: I’m gonna close it myself, everyone hates this question anyway

Comment: ***Please vote to close this question.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No there isn't.**

In English, "underscore" has no special significance. In fact in English Language terms underscore isn't really recognized as a character - it was originally used in typewriters, where the typist would do underlining by typing the text, backspacing over it, and then typing underscores over the characters.  It was carried over to to telex and computer character representations, and is now pretty much used only in computer programming. It isn't officially classed as 'punctuation' in English.

Every grouping that includes letters, digits and underscore is extremely specialized in that it applies to a specific computer language. Each language or application may define a technical term to for the grouping, but it would be specific to that application. So the usage is not frequent enough to have acquired a common name.

Comment: This is the most explained/best thing I've gotten so far, so unless a new answer comes along with new leads this will be the accepted.